# how to write a client/server app in heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am quite new to heroku and I reached a bump in my dev...

I am trying to write a server/client kind of application...on the server side I will have a DB(I installed postgresql for python) and I was hoping I could reach the server, for now, via a python client(for test purposes) and send data/queries and perform basic tasks on the DB.

I am using python with Heroku, I manage to install the DB and it seems to be working(i.e i can query, insert, delete, etc...)
now all i want is to write a server(in python) that would be my app and would listen on a port and receive messages and then perform whatever tasks it is asked to do...I tought about using sockets for this and have managed to write a basic server/client locally...however when I deploy the app on heroku i cannot connect to the server and my code is basically worthless

can somebody plz advise on the basic framework for this sort of requirements...surely I am not the first guy to want to write a client/server app...if you could point to a tutorial/doc i would be much obliged.

Thx

Answer (score 3):

Heroku is for developing Web (`HTTP`, `HTTPS`) applications. You can't deploy code that uses `socket` to Heroku.

If you want to run your app on Heroku, the easier way is to use a web framework (Flask, CherryPy, Django...). They usually also come with useful libraries and abstractions for you to talk to your database.